# Implement SSO login with or without Membership

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, login, sso

I need to implement SSO for four different domains, say

```
abc.com
pqr.com
sql.com
xyz.com
```

Now, I have already login system for two of my applications using Membership. But now requirement is changed, challenge is to make Single Sign On.

```
Me: Can we have subdomains?
client: no !!!

Me: Can we have single database and separate session management server?
client: NO !!!
```

After that I create a POC in which I am able to share a cookie across the multiple domains but issue is it need to ping and bounce back to all domains on user browser which led the larger login time.

Can I have suggestion how to get it done?

Comment: Are these AD domains? Have you considered ADFS and claims based security. Lots of infrastructure baked into .Net 4.5 to support this.

Comment: yes i have look on active directory, but they will help only if all sites are hosted on same server if i am wrong please correct me

Comment: Active Directory Federated Services will create a claims based security bridge between your identity provider (AD) and the consuming application. I'm not sure if a single instance of ADFS can use multiple domains, it might. But a consuming app can be configured to accept claims tokens from multiple providers.